# What is wrong in this code in this problem

Tags: recursion

Suppose you have a string, S, made up of only 'a's and 'b's. Write a recursive function that checks if the string was generated using the following rules:
a. The string begins with an 'a'
b. Each 'a' is followed by nothing or an 'a' or "bb"
c. Each "bb" is followed by nothing or an 'a'
If all the rules are followed by the given string, return true otherwise return false.
Input format :
String S
Output format :
'true' or 'false'

```
int length(char input[]) {
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0;input[i]!='\0';i++) {
        count++;
    } 
    return count;
}
bool checkAB(char input[], int start, int end) {
    // Write your code here
    if(start==end) {
        return true;
    }
    if(input[start]!='a') {
        return false;
    }
    if(input[start+1]=='a') {
        checkAB(input,start+1,end);
    }
    if(input[start+1]=='b'&&input[start+2]=='b') {
            checkAB(input,start+3,end);
    }
    
}
bool checkAB(char input[]) {
    int len=length(input);
    return checkAB(input,0,len);
}
```

its working for all cases except for cases like aba abababa?
So what's wrong in my code

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem you would usually solve with a state machine.
Your check AB function could have a new parameter "state".
Then you could make a state machine that react exactly like the description tells you to do:

```
enum states{ A, BB }

bool checkAB(char input[], int start, int end, int state) {
    // Write your code here
    if(start>=end) {
        return true;
    }
    if(input[0]!='a') {
        return false;
    }
    if (state==A)
    {
      if(input[start+1]=='a')
        return checkAB(input,start+1,end,A);
      if(input[start+1]=='b' && input[start+2]=='b')
        return checkAB(input,start+2,end,BB);
    }
    if (state==BB)
    {
      if(input[start+1]=='a')
        return checkAB(input,start+1,end,A);
    }
    return false;
}
bool checkAB(char input[]) {
    int len=length(input);
    return checkAB(input,0,len,A);
}
```

Comment: I didnt understand what you are trying to say

Comment: You seem to not have a clear understanding of what is a state machine, so I suggest you to watch this quick video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Yicg2TTMPs . It explains very briefly my proposed implementation.